# Confusion about meaning of 1, 1', and 2 in finding $S_3$ irreps, and how they correspond to the representation of the group elements

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I am working through the paper *Non-Abelian Discrete Symmetries in Particle Physics*, which can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.3552/%22here%22). I am confused about the following highlighted passage found on pg. 8:

[image]

I understand this follows from the fact that there are two one dimensional irreps and one two dimensional irreps. My main question is asking if my following interpretation of this is correct:

The above statement is saying that the representation of each group $g\in G$ element can be written as the direct sum

\begin{align}
D(g)=\mathbf{1}_{g}\oplus\mathbf{1'}_g\oplus \mathbf{2}_g.
\end{align}

I don't think this is correct, but I'm a bit stuck at the moment. Could somebody please clarify how I go about finding $\mathbf{1}, \mathbf{1'}$, and $\mathbf{2}$, and how exactly that corresponds to the representation of the group elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some context might be helpful:

In the paper you refer to, $m_n$ denotes the number of $n$-dimensional irreps of $S_3$. The passage you are reading to is trying to count how many irreps there are of each dimension.

The paper quotes two well-known facts:

- The order of the group equals $m_1 + 4m_2 + 9m_3 + 16m_4 + \dots $
- The number of conjugacy classes equals $m_1 + m_2 + m_3 + m_4 + \dots$

Since the order of $S_3$ is $6$, and the number of conjugacy classes is $3$, the only possibility is that
$$ m_1 = 2, \ \  \ m_2 = 1, \ \  \ m_3 = m_4 = \dots = 0.$$

The irreps of $S_3$ are:

- The one-dimensional "identity" irrep $\mathbf{1}$, where every element is represented by $1$.
- The one-dimensioanl "alternating" irrep $\mathbf{1}'$, where every even element is represented by $1$ and every odd element is represented by $-1$.
- The two-dimensional irrep $\mathbf{2}$, obtained by viewing elements of $S_3$ as $2\times 2$ matrices describing symmetries of a triangle.

Your statement that "the representation of each group element $g \in G$ can be written as the direct sum $\mathbf{1}_g \oplus \mathbf{1}'_g \oplus \mathbf{2}_g$" doesn't make a great deal of sense to me, I'm afraid! There is no such thing as "the representation". There are *many* possible representations of $S_3$: any direct sum of $\mathbf{1}$, $\mathbf{1}'$ and $\mathbf{2}$ will do.

Comment: Thank you, that was quite helpful. I just have a few follow up questions. (1) How does one arrive at the fact that $\mathbf{1'}$ was the "alternating" irrep?(2) I have the exact same question for the the ire $\mathbf{2}$. (3) Lastly, when you say that "any direct sum of $\mathbf{1}, \mathbf{1'}$ and $\mathbf{2}$ will do, what exactly do you mean, and how is does that differ from what I wrote down in the post?

Comment: I don't quite follow... $\mathbb{1}'$ is just the standard notation for the alternating irrep. And the "alternating irrep" is just the standard name for this irrep.

Comment: I mean that $\mathbb{1}$ is a representation, $\mathbb{1}'$ is a representation, $\mathbb{2}$ is a representation, $\mathbb{1} \oplus \mathbb{1}$ is a representation, $\mathbb{1} \oplus \mathbb{2}$ is a representation, $\mathbb{1}' \oplus \mathbb{2} \oplus \mathbb{2} \oplus \mathbb{2}$ is a representation, $\mathbb{1} \oplus \mathbb{1} \oplus \mathbb{1}' \oplus \mathbb{2} \oplus \mathbb{2} \oplus \mathbb{2}$ is a representation... You get the idea.

Comment: I see. I suppose if I were to rephrase it it would be as follows: When use the characters to solve for certain information, I arrive at the fact that there are two one dimensional solutions, and one two dimensional irreps *and that's it*. I don't know anything about what maps to what (and hence I don't know that it is the alternating irrep). It seems like, should I not ask this question, I would be told to "just remember it is the alternating rep", if that helps clarify.

Comment: I do get the idea of your previous comment, yes. Thank you that was helpful.

Comment: I described the alternating rep in my answer! In the alternating rep, $e$, $(123)$ and $(132)$ are represented by the $1\times 1$ matrix $1$, whereas $(12)$, $(13)$ and $(23)$ are represented by the matrix $-1$. Is this comprehensible?

Comment: ... and for the two-dimensional irrep, I would like you to imagine an equilateral triangle, whose corners are labelled $1$, $2$ and $3$. Think of the permutation in $S_3$ as symmetries of the triangle. For example, $(123)$ is a rotation through $120$ degrees, and $(12)$ is a reflection that exchanges corners $1$ and $2$ but fixes corner $3$. These rotations and reflections can be represented by $2 \times 2$ matrices, like in usual linear algebra. These matrices _are_ the two-dimensional irrep of $S_3$. Does this make sense?

Comment: I think I see it now. I'm going to think about it more tonight. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Would you like to know how we know that these reps are irreducible?

Comment: Sure, yea if you wouldn't mind adding that to your answer. I could certainly use that as a reference.

Comment: You just need to know a standard fact. Define the character $\chi(g)$ of a group element $g$ in a given representation to be the trace of the matrix representing $g$. A representation is irreducible iff $\frac 1 {|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi(g)^\star \chi(g) = 1$. Perhaps you could calculate these for the three reps I gave you, and check.

Comment: Finally, there is a very simple way to prove that two irreducible representations are inequivalent. Given two inequivalent irreps with characters $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$, you can show that $\frac 1 {|G|}\sum_{g \in G} \chi_1(g)^\star \chi_2 (g) = 0$. Perhaps you could check this too. If you want something to check against, the characters are in Table 1 on page 9 of your paper.

Comment: Thank you, those were all very helpful. I think I see my confusion now. In the highlighted section in my post he says that the irreps include two singles $\mathbf{1}$ and $\mathbf{1'}$, and a doublet $\mathbf{2}$. This language certainly makes it sound like the representation itself is actually a singlet or doublet, but really the  $\mathbf{1}$, $\mathbf{1'}$, and $\mathbf{2}$ denote *mappings* $G\rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V)$. Do I have this right?

Comment: Yes, every representation is a mapping from $G \to GL(V)$. For the one-dimensional representations, $V = \mathbb C$, and for the two-dimensional representation, $V = \mathbb C^2$.

Comment: But of course, the $\mathbb{1}$ and $\mathbb{1}'$ are two different mappings. For example $\mathbb{1}$ maps $(12)$ to $[1]$ whereas $\mathbb{1}'$ maps $(12)$ to $[-1]$.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Now, I'm not sure if I should post this as another question or not (just let me know if you'd rather me do that). If you look at equations (36) and (40) in the paper, it seems like they are saying that $\mathbf{1}, \mathbf{1'}, \mathbf{2}$ are actually those elements written to the right (i.e. not mappings). What am I missing here? Like I said, let me know if you want me to post a new question on this.

Comment: Would you like to discuss this in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55594/discussion-between-kenny-wong-and-the-trivial-solution).